# Adding numbers in asp

Tags: string, asp-classic, sum, addition

How do I add the following strings to show the total in asp page?

```
<%=moviesA%>
<%=moviesB%>
```

Currently, moviesA = 1000 and moviesB = 400 (both strings are dynamic). I want to display "There are currently 1400 movies in our archives."

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use the CInt function to convert string to int and then add. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fctcwhw9%28v=vs.84%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand how this works in my context. I will probably need to see the actual code I need.

Comment: `Response.write "There are currently "& CInt(moviesA)+CInt(moviesB) &"movies in our archives."`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this you would first add the two numbers and the use `Cstr()` to change it to a string for writing.

Example:

```
totalmovies=moviesA+moviesB
response.write ("There are currently " + cstr(totalmovies) + " movies in our archives.")
```

Note if moviesA and moviesB are Strings already then you need to change them to int before doing the addition then line 1 would be:

```
totalmovies=cint(moviesA) + cint(moviesB)
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both! The **cint** method did the trick.

The code I ended up using has a slightly different structure...

```
There are currently
<%totalmovies=cint(moviesA) + cint(moviesB)
response.write (cstr(totalmovies))%>
movies in our archives.
```

Cheers!